# Test Service Report Creation

Tags: apex, failing-tests, field-service-lightning

I made a trigger on Service Report and I'm trying to write a test class for it, but I get this error every time I try to insert a Service Report in a test function or my `makeData` function:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, ORA-20001: ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CACCESS",
> line 3223ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CACCESS", line 1431ORA-06512: at
> "SNEEZY.CACCESS", line 3193ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CACCESS", line
> 2848ORA-06512: at line 1SQLException while executing plsql statement:
> {call cAccess.check_entity_access_proc_ncu(?,?,?,?,?,?)}(EXCLUDED,
> EXCLUDED, 0WO0400000165uU, EXCLUDED, true, false);
> [conn=STANDARD:1:1:3484:19721]: []

I've been inserting it in the following way:

```
        WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder()
        insert wo;
        ServiceReportLayout srl = [select id from ServiceReportLayout where DeveloperName = 'FSR Template'];
        ServiceReport sr = new ServiceReport(ParentId = wo.Id, Template = srl.Id);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new InsertUsingNamedCredsMock());
        insert sr;
```

Also I used what was mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g9k2QAA) once, but got the same result.
Tested with enabled and disabled trigger logic.
Here is code used in `setMock()` method:

```
@isTest
public class InsertUsingNamedCredsMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement the respond method to simulate the HTTP response
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
        // Create a mock HTTP response
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"status": "success"}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've run into a "dwarf" error (named after the seven dwarves in Snow White), and the "ORA" bits of that are issues in the Oracle Database layer (one of the collection of database solutions that Salesforce leverages). You'll need to go through the [official Salesforce Support channel](https://help.salesforce.com/s/?language=en_US) to get help with this one unless a Salesforce employee who can investigate this comes by and shares their findings.